# How to make a django package modify settings.py?

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-apps

I'm trying to set up a django application, which itself has a few dependencies. One of these ([crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/index.html)) requires a few settings to be set in settings.py before the application will work. I know what defaults I want to use. How can I make my app modify the default settings on the fly? Specifically:

1. How do I ensure that whatever custom settings file I create is recognized as a settings file by django?
2. How do I actually modify the settings?

For (2) above it looks like [this link on Django Code](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#Accessingandmodifyingexistingsettings) may work, but it doesn't explain how to go about (1). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @eykanal, I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it? How?

Comment: @tjanez - After reading around, I decided that the inability to do this is by design. The user should have to explicitly include any required packages so as to ensure they don't conflict with other stuff they may have installed. I just took the route of writing a very detailed instruction list to make sure they install everything that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the crispy forms settings in the main settings.py but if you prefer dissociated the dependencies settings app from your settings, you must create crispy_settings.py file and import it in your settings file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I specifically don't want to have to modify the main `settings.py` file. How do I make a settings.py file that gets picked up by django?